# Do I have this diagramed out right?

Tags: electrical

Wire diagram:
[image]

Looking for either confirmation or help of its wrong.

The above diagram shows what I’m planning on doing. There’s an existing light switch in my basement that operates the top outlet in 2 receptacles. I’m going to run canned lights in the ceiling where there were no lights previously and add a new switch so that each switch operates a series of lights.

Also I know the neutral wire is missing in the diagram. Did it just to save space since they’ll all be wired and capped together in the switch box.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do.  As it's drawn, the left switch will switch your outlets, the right switch will switch the lights attached to the top-right cable, and any lights attached to the top-middle cable will be always on.  Is that your intention?

Comment: What I’d like to do is have the left switch operate the outlets coming from that bottom cable and the lights coming from the middle top cable. Ideally I’d like to get rid of that switched receptacle but I think I’d have to pull the 14/3 cable and I’d have to tear out more drywall for that, so I’m ok with leaving them as switched.

Comment: I had assumed the cable you labeled "main" came from your panel.  Is that not the case?

Comment: Yes. The main is coming from the panel. Well maybe with a few stops at outlets along the way, but it ultimately ends up at the main box.

Comment: You can get rid of the switched receptacles without pulling the 14-3 out, you know, right?

Comment: Ahhhh, missed that he wanted to drop the switched on the outlet in the comments. The below solution does that. Now the picture makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As drawn, your left switch will operate your switched outlets, the right switch will operate the lights attached to the top-right cable, and any lights attached to the top-middle cable will be always-on.

Assuming what you want is for the left switch to operate the lights attached to the top-middle cable, the right switch to operate the lights attached to the top-right cable, and for the outlets to be always-on, you need to connect things more like this:

[image: Wiring Diagram]

I've not drawn neutrals or grounds.  All the white wires should be connected together; they will all be acting as neutrals.  The grounds should be connected as in your original diagram.

Comment: FWIW - the outlets will no longer be switched in this diagram. Also, (personally) recommend not putting 5 14awg wires under one nut. (just use one addiitonal nut, and keep the outlet hots together for example).

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. Greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You can do five #14s under a red or tan wire nut.